# Can't erase my phone

Tags: iphone

I can't erase all content and settings on my iPhone 6s+.

When I enter my passcode, restrictions PIN, and iCloud password it displays an error telling me that verification failed, there was an error connecting to iCloud.

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet? This can be over WiFi or mobile data. Your phone needs to connect to iCloud to check if Find my iPhone is on before erasing the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the phone in recovery mode and then unlocking the iCloud restriction afterwards? Hold down the sleep/wake and Home button until the iPhone goes into recovery mode and then erase it by connecting it to iTunes via a Lightning cable. Once the phone is erased it will require you to login to your iCloud account to unlock it.